# SwiftUI custom UINavigationBar color and transparency

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using `UIToolbar` and `UINavigationBar`, but for this example I will use `navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)` for custom transparency and color. Not sure where the issue lies but the `UINavigationBar` doesn't remain true black while there is no list content behind it. As you can see in the image bellow it is slightly gray, and I believe its just the nature of using the `withAlphaComponent(0.4)`, as I raise the number it gets darker but it also lowers the intensity of the transparency.

Here is an image of `UINavigationBar` without any content behind it:
[image]

Here is an image of a sample when list rows are behind. I like how transparent it is here.
[image]

Looking at for example native app on iPhone like messages, they perfectly use what I am trying to achieve. Their `UIToolbar` remains true black until messages are passed behind it. Same can be seen in an app like Signal and Facebook messanger.

For example (messages app) here it's true black when empty:
[image]

And finally when messages are behind:
[image]

Here is my code for simplicity of the case:

```
 init() {
        // Customize UINavigationBar
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    }
```

How would I achieve the same effect such as in the message apps? I am aware I could completely remove the `ini()...` and just use the system default scheme, but then I cannot control the intensity, colors etc.

Comment: Consider to create a custom NavigationBar and use it throughout the app.